# Django language switcher is not persistent

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

Hello I'm struggling with my language switcher.

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de','Deutsch'),
    ('en','English')
]
```

urls.py:

```
path('setlang', views.setlang, name='setlang'),
```

index.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'setlang' %}">{% trans "English" %}</a>
```

views.py

```
def setlang(request):
    logger.error(get_language())
    if get_language() == 'de':
        activate('en')
    else:
        activate('de')
    logger.error(get_language())
    return redirect('index')
```

Output from logger.error(get_language()) -> 'de' than 'en'.

It's everytime 'de'! Even if I set LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'! I've no idea where the 'de' is coming from.

The problem is maybe the reload, which is forced by the return redirect('index')?

Translation in general works.

Has anyone an idea how I can stick to the language which is selected and not fall back to default?

Comment: `activate(..)` is only for the lifetime of the request.

Comment: S: a global variable? Where is the 'de' coming from?

Comment: in order of sequence: the URL pattern, the cookie, the ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header, and finally the `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

Comment: If I set LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' I still get logger.error(get_language()) -> de. Is LANGUAGE_CODE the most or less dominate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`activate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate) is not supposed to be persistent. Indeed, as the documentation says:

> Fetches the translation object for a given language and activates it as the current translation object **for the current thread.**

It thus "dies" after the the thread is finished.

You can set the cookie of the [**`LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME) to activate a different language:

```
from django.conf import settings


def setlang(request):
    logger.error(get_language())
    if get_language() == 'de':
        lang = 'en'
    else:
        lang = 'de'
    response = redirect('index')
    response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang)
    return response
```